# How to get assignee of an issue via JIRA REST API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm still new to using JIRA and currently I'm using curl to invoke jira rest commands. I would like to get the assignee of an issue via rest but I can't seem to find the way how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to query for particular issue like this:

```
http://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUEKEY
```

you will receive a `JSON` object with nested `assignee` object looking like this:

```
    "assignee": {
          "self": "http://hostname/rest/api/2/user?username=abcde",
          "name": "abcde",
          "emailAddress": "mail@abc.com",
          "avatarUrls": {....}
}
```

Comment: I already came across this query and got a result. My problem was how to get the assignee from the result.
I just realized now that all I need to do is call  the fields then assignee from the result like this: `$result.fields.assignee`

Anyway, thank you very much for the help. I will set this one as the answer since this is more understandable from others' POV.

Answer (score 3):

Just look right [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-version-2-tutorial#JIRARESTAPIVersion2Tutorial-SimpleIssueResponse):

You have to request the whole issue information. To do that, you have to know the JIRA Issue you want to have the assignee of. You will find it in "fields" -> "assignee".